# How to find out if something will collide with something in Unity (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to make a 2D game in Unity and I was curious if there is a way to check if there WILL be a collision between 2 objects rather then telling me WHEN they actually collide.

For Example - I am making a Space Invaders game and I want to check if any one of the space invaders on the edges will collide with a edge before they actually move in a C# script.  I coded in Game Maker Studio and I remember that function being available but I am having a hard time finding out if its possible in Unity.  Is this possible in Unity?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its possible, you would have to do some sort of raycasting in the direction that the gameobject is moving you can check [This Link for Physics.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to see how to go about doing what youd like

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 10))
            print("There is something in front of the object!");

    }
}
```